# Styles lost with different url in Laravel

Tags: php, iis, laravel, web.config-transform

I use Laravel in my web project. I have specified these routes for unauthenticated users.

```
Route::group(array("before" => "guest"), function() {
    // Show the login page for the user
    Route::get("/", array("as" => "homepage", function() {
        return View::make("unauthenticated.login");
    }));

    Route::get("/account/login", array("as" => "account-login-get", function() {
        return View::make("unauthenticated.login");
    }));
});
```

If I access `/` my page looks correct. If I try to accesss `/account/login`, I don't get the stylesheets. I think this has to do with the rewrite. I use IIS on Windows Server 2012 and I have this kind of web.config file in the public folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Move to index.php">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have two projects. In one of them this works but in the other it doesn't. What might be wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `URL::asset()` to link to the stylesheet.
Because in `/` it links to (for example) `example.com/css/style.css`
And if you're in `/account/login`, it will look for the stylesheet in `example.com/account/login/css/style.css`

I use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/style.min.css') }}"/>` in my master blade template.

Hope it helps